# Disable rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

In our project, if you run `rake test`, terrible things happen; you need to run `rake spec`. I can't seem to figure out how to re-define `rake test` to just output a message suggesting running `rake spec` instead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On your Rakefile at the end:

```
Rake::Task["test"].clear
task 'test' do
    puts "use 'rake spec'"
end
```

Or even better

```
Rake::Task["test"].clear
task 'test' do
    Rake::Task["spec"].invoke
end
```

Comment: FYI, you'll likely want to depend on the `:environment` so you'll want something like this `task test: :environment do`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work with Rails 5+ where running `rails test`. You can overwrite the `rake` task and it works when you run `rake test` but when you run `rails test` it still runs the built-in Rails test runner.